# Iterating over a Data.Set until success

Tags: haskell, set, option-type

Suppose I have a function representing some computation that can fail

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
```

If I have a list `l`, I can find the first (when scanning left-to-right) item in the list on which `f` succeeds using `findList f l`, where `findList` is the following function

```
findList :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
findList f [] = Nothing
findList f (x : xs) = case f x of
  Nothing -> findList f xs
  Just y -> Just y
```

(or using, e.g., [`firstJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:firstJust) from the `extra` package).

### Question.

What do I do if I want to do the same thing with a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) from `containers`?

That is, I want a function with signature

```
findSet :: (a -> Maybe b) -> Set a -> Maybe b
```

which is equivalent to

```
findSet f s = findList f (Set.toList s)
```

The line above works as an implementation. However, I don't want to create the intermediate list `Set.toList s` (even with lazy evaluation, there is still some unnecessary overhead, right?).

I also don't want to iterate over the entire set once a successful item has been found, as in the following implementation:

```
findSet f s = foldl g Nothing s
  where
    g Nothing x = f x
    g (Just y) _ = Just y
```

So is there a good way of traversing over a set "left-to-right", applying a computation that can fail to each member, and stopping at the first successful result?

Comment: when called with a reducer function which is non-strict in its 2nd parameter, `foldr` works left to right. your first function is `\f -> listToMaybe . mapMaybe f :: (a1 -> Maybe a) -> [a1] -> Maybe a` and second is `\f -> listToMaybe . mapMaybe f . toList :: Foldable t => (a1 -> Maybe a) -> t a1 -> Maybe a`. if your data type's `Foldable` instance defines `toList` which is lazy, the overhead should be minuscule, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the fact that the `Set` is an instance of `Foldable`. You can thus implement a `Fold` function with:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

findSet :: (a -> Maybe b) -> Set a -> Maybe b
findSet f = foldr ((<|>) . f) Nothing
```

this can in fact work with all instances of `Foldable`:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

findSet :: (Alternative g, Foldable f) => (a -> g b) -> f a -> g b
findSet f = foldr ((<|>) . f) Nothing
```

or as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463050/iterating-over-a-data-set-until-success#comment117500836_66463186), we can make use of [**`First`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First), since `First` will select the first `Just`, and thus work with:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

findSet :: Foldable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> Maybe b
findSet f = getFirst . foldMap (First . f)
```

The implementation of `toList` is also implemented in terms of `Foldable`:

```
toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]
toList = foldr (:) []
```

so what we here do is instead of first wrapping it in a cons and then unwrap it, immediately apply `f` and work with the implementation of [**`(<|>) :: Alternate f => f a -> f a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-).

Comment: Ah, great! I had a feeling there would be a generalization to `Foldable`, but this gives a generalization to `(Foldable t, Alternative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f b`. Neat. Thank you!

Comment: I like `foldMap` as a primitive much more than `foldr`. Thinking about how to use it instead, you actually get a quite nice alternative implementation: `findSet f = foldMap (First . f)`, which, for the performance conscious, can just be `findSet = coerce foldMap` with a suitably painful type signature on `coerce`.

Comment: what is `Alternate`, and what does `import Control.Applicative((<|>))` do in the code snippet that uses `First`?

Comment: @WillNess: it's *Atwood's duck*.

Comment: according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), that "duck" thing is something you do to your *corporate supervisor*, not a person asking for help (or future readers). and the duck here breaks the picture, unlike in the original story.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to share a little trick somebody on IRC once showed me: early-exit-on-success is just another interpretation of early-exit-on-error. With that in mind, consider using `Either b ()` instead of `Maybe b`; then

```
findOne :: (a -> Either b ()) -> Set a -> Either b ()
findOne = traverse_
```

Hardly even worth naming. If you must have `Maybe`, you can simply wrap this with the obvious isomorphism.

```
findOneMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> Set a -> Maybe b
findOneMaybe f = to . traverse_ (from . f) where
    from = maybe (Right ()) Left
    to = either Just (const Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniel! This is indeed a good trick. I considered using it for my use case before, but ran into the issue that I was relying on monadicity of `Maybe` somewhere else, so there's a tradeoff of having to rewrite some do blocks and what not. Nevertheless, this is a nice use of `traverse`!

Comment: @ArtemMavrin It is easy to convert `a -> Maybe b` into `a -> Either b ()` right before you hand it off to `traverse`; just compose with `maybe (Right ()) Left`. Similarly it is easy to convert back with `either Just (const Nothing)`.

Comment: Another issue: `Set` (from `collections` at least) isn't `Traversable` :(

Comment: @ArtemMavrin `traverse_` (as opposed to `traverse`!) does not require `Traversable`, despite its name.