# What is a clean way of writing this function?

Tags: haskell

I would like some help with a problem I'm trying to solve. Let's say I have a type called `Thing`:

```hs
data Thing = ....
```

And I want to write a function that, given a string, tries to match it with some stuff in my state and return a `Thing`:

```hs
findFirstMatch :: String -> State (Maybe Thing)
```

The thing is, to match that string, it needs a list of possible strings to match it with. That list is provided by a function defined for my state:

```hs
getPossibilities :: State String
```

Now, I need to call a third function that receives the original string and one of the possibilities, and returns a `Maybe Thing`:

```hs
tryToMatch :: String -> String -> State (Maybe Thing)
```

How can I write `findFirstMatch`? I thought of doing this but it doesn't seem that clean, and it feels like there might be something already implemented:

```hs
findFirstMatch :: String -> State (Maybe Thing)
findFirstMatch str = do
    xs <- getPossibilities
    firstNotNull (map (tryToMatch str) xs)

firstNotNull :: [State (Maybe Thing)] -> State (Maybe Thing)
firstNotNull [] = return Nothing
firstNotNull (x:xs) = do
    r <- x
    case r of
        Just _ -> return r
        Nothing -> firstNotNull xs
```

Comment: You in the same class as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66463050/791604), by any chance?

Comment: Lol, nope, but I see the similarities. The thing is I don't have a monad with a list inside it, but a list of monads with elements inside them. That's why I had to write that ugly `firstNotNull` thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can clean this up quite a bit if you write `firstNotNull` without using `State`.  A very simple pass would be:

```hs
firstNotNull :: [Maybe Thing] -> Maybe Thing
firstNotNull [] = Nothing
firstNotNull (Just x:_) = Just x
firstNotNull Nothing:xs = firstNotNull xs
```

Furthermore, you can simplify even further by using some functions from `Data.Maybe`:

```hs
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, listToMaybe)

firstNotNull :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
firstNotNull = listToMaybe . catMaybes
```

Now, let's turn our attention to `findFirstMatch` to see how we can use this simplified version of `firstNotNull`.  The first question is: Does `tryToMatch` really need to live in `State`?  After all, it already has access to both `String`s that it's matching on.  If you can change its type to `tryToMatch :: String -> String -> Maybe Thing`, then you're basically good to go.

On the other hand, if `tryToMatch` really does need to live in `State`, then there's just a little bit more to do: we need to pass `firstNotNull` a `[Maybe Thing]`, but we have a `[State (Maybe Thing)]`.  We can fix this by using `sequenceA`, as in:

```hs
findFirstMatch :: String -> State (Maybe Thing)
findFirstMatch str = do
    xs <- getPossibilities
    fmap firstNotNull $ sequenceA (map (tryToMatch str) xs)
```

Note that this only works if your `State` monad is lazy enough.  If it's too strict, it will end up finding all matches, doing far too much work (and screwing up performance) and then return the first one.

From here, we can recognize that the usage of `sequenceA` and `map` can be reduced to a single call to `traverse`, as in:

```hs
    fmap firstNotNull $ traverse (tryToMatch str) xs
```

This seems much cleaner!

---

Of course, we can still go further if we really want.  It's not clear that the below changes actually make the code *cleaner* (rather, there's a strong argument that they make it harder to read), but let's have some fun anyway.

Rather than use `do`, we can choose to make this a one-liner with an appropriate use of monadic bind:

```hs
findFirstMatch str = getPossibilities $ \xs -> (fmap firstNotNull $ sequenceA (map (tryToMatch str) xs))
```

The inner lambda can be nicely eta-reduced to:

```hs
findFirstMatch str = getPossibilities >>= fmap firstNotNull . sequenceA . map (tryToMatch str)
```

And this too can be eta-reduced:

```hs
findFirstMatch = (getPossibilities >>=) . ((fmap firstNotNull . sequenceA) .) . map . tryToMatch
```

And while we're at it, why even have a definition of `firstNotNull` when we can inline it!

```hs
findFirstMatch :: String -> State (Maybe Thing)
findFirstMatch = (getPossibilities >>=) . ((fmap (listToMaybe . catMaybes) . sequenceA) .) . map . tryToMatch
```

There, your whole function in one messy line!

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. I didn't expect such a detailed answer. I'll go over what you said.

Comment: Yes, `tryToMatch` needs to live in `State` because of some other requirements. Now, you said that this works if my `State` monad is lazy enough. I omitted the details, but my monad is actually the `StateT` monad transformer applied to the `Except` monad, both provided by `Control.Monad.Trans`. I'm not sure if that is lazy enough, but because of the new type of `firstNotNull` it seems like it needs to receive all the results already calculated and then returns the first one.

Comment: If you're using `Control.Monad.Trans.State`, then you're using the lazy one (see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State.html)), so you should be fine.  It may look like it calculates everything, but laziness is pretty cool.  Try this out: `evalState (head <$> sequence (repeat get)) 4`.  Notice that it creates an infinite list of `get` actions, sequences them, and then takes the head of the list.  With lazy StateT, this produces `4`, but with strict, it loops forever.

Comment: Well then this is a nice solution. And by the way, cool one liner